Can’t seem to get threaded connection to not leak
I just replaced my electric water heater and I can’t seem to get the cold connection to not leak. There is a drip that is in the same spot no matter how much or little tape I use or how tight it is. And there is a droplet that seems to be forcing out of the tape not even near the connection. Any suggestions on how to fix this?  The hot side is completely fine.

How about a picture so we can see what you've got.

I’ve added pictures, I think  lol

I’ve been scouring the web and I’m wondering if I need pipe dope and tape?  I’ve never had to used both on water connections before

I would start at the beginning, but check the threads very carefully for any damage.  You use dope or tape, usually not both.  Very rare, but some fittings might need a bit of time(a day or two) to seal completely

Thanks. It’s not a massive leak so maybe I’ll just monitor it for a couple of days and if it doesn’t seal as you suggested, I’ll take it apart again and check the fittings.

It doesn't take much to cause a leak. Did you wrap the tape clockwise? If you don't, sometimes it will bunch up. Just sayin'!

When you take the connection apart, you could verify that the thread is tapered and not straight thread. If it is a straight thread, the tape is wrong approach and the fitting should have a rubber seal.

@HoneyDo I did wrap clockwise.

@jpa the same fitting is on the hot side and not leaking?  Could they have made a mistake when manufacturing on the thread?

@Michelle Sometimes you get lucky even when using fittings incorrectly. But yeah, tapered fittings is what you would expect to find on a water heater.

Have you inspected both the male and female fittings for damage or "out of round"-ness?

I have had to use pipe dope or PTFE plus pipe dope to seal certain problematic threaded connections. In my experience PTFE tape alone does not work on some threaded connectons.
In Europe and in British Commonwealth countries threaded water pipe is sometimes sealed with "plumber's hemp" plus pipe dope. If you don't want to order plumber's hemp you could perhaps try heavy cotton or linen thread (plus pipe dope). I think the use of the hemp was necessary for parallel threads but should work to seal problematic tapered threads.

There are two things I'd try differently:

For whatever reason the white PTFE tape one buys at retail tends to be thin, while the stuff that gets included with other products (air tools, faucets, etc) tends to be insanely thin (borderline useless). A few years ago I began using the blue PTFE tape instead. It is a much heavier film and the extra body seems to help.

Pipe dope, especially the varieties that include PTFE, works wonders. The paste seems to actually contribute to the seal, and the PTFE additive lubricates more than plain dope paste without PTFE does.


It's not crazy to use both tape and dope, but I would wager that either blue tape or dope with PTFE will help you make the connection dry.
Don't discount the possibility that the parts could be damaged, even fresh from the factory. Sometimes the threads just aren't machined right - they might be cut too deeply, for example. If nothing else works you might try exchanging that brass part.

Thanks for all of this info!  I’ll get some PTFE blue tape today (if I can find some near me) and check the fitting as well.

+1 for blue/pink tape. Getting the thicker tape was a game changer for me.

I usually wrap plumbers tape around the threads three times clock-wise.  The tape might be called PTFE Thread Seal Tape. I also insure a small portion of that tape is sticking out so as to be visible after the joint is tightened. I see no tape in the picture.  I do not use any putty.
Since the other answer mentioned it, I use the blue tape.  It is thicker.  A plumber recommended it to me.  He called it "Blue Monster".  In my instance, I got it when I purchased a new water heater at a real plumbing supply company (not a box store).

The tape is the white section that is seen below the brass connector on top. I’ve tried different amounts of tape and no go.
